# How to print correct date in php

Tags: php, date

Hi i am trying to display current date using php code when i run   my code it  is displaying 1 day back date  why it is happening in my code how can i solve this problem

Here is my code

**date.php**

```
   <?php
    $myfile=date('m-d-Y');
    echo $myfile;
    ?>
```

here i am getting output : `09-22-2014`
and  output should be `09-23-2014`

where i am wrong  how can   i achieve my desired  output

Any help will be appreciated

Thanky

Comment: your server and yourself may not be in the same timezone

Comment: my server is in kolkatta,chennai  time zone

Comment: Wait a few hours and try again. If the date suddenly comes right you'll know it's a timezone problem.

Comment: and you live in moscow?

Comment: use [**date_default_timezone_set**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: Why all the downvotes? What's wrong with the question? O.o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need set default time zone before call date function

`date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$myfile=date('m-d-Y');
echo $myfile;`

Comment: This will give you only the correct date not the correct time.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set your timezone:

```
date_default_timezone_set ( string $timezone_identifier )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Here is a link to supported timezones:

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to set defauolt timezone first, then you can get the desired data

```
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
    echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s'); //Returns IST
```

This will print the current time and date.
Note: You can call date function according to your needs.